# Как сделать так, чтобы кнопка button плавно исчезла, после нажатия по ней?

Tags: html, jquery

Дана кнопка button. Нужно сделать так, чтобы она плавно, например в течении 2 секунд, исчезла, после нажатия по ней. Как это сделать?

Comment: Исчезала в течение 2 секунд или исчезала через 2 секунды?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как например:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var $this = $(this);
  
  
  setTimeout(function() { 
    $this.slideUp(2000);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  
<a href="#" class="btn">hide button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
 $(this).addClass('btnAnimationFade');
});
```

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.btnAnimationFade{
    animation: btnAnimationFade 2s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes btnAnimationFade{
    100%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn">hide button</a>
```

Comment: Чет как-то слишком замудрено) намного проще задать transition:2s для .btn и opacity:0 для .btnAnimateFade